# Trying to run laravel on macbook - getting exception Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: laravel

I get this error exception when trying to execute the command

```
curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash
```

I am referring to laravel documentation at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x to run laravel on Mac using Docker desktop.

While eventually the installation is successful (in spite of the error mentioned above) - I am unable to execute the command `.vendor/bin/sail up` as directed the documentation. Upon checking it appears that there is no directory BIN in Vendor directory under example-app folder.

This is the error I get

> [ErrorException]
> copy(/opt/example-app/vendor/composer/tmp-0a6597f2f29f634451109e2d3721420d):
> Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Can anyone help me with this error?

Thanks

Comment: Did you install Docker?

Comment: Yes I have docker desktop installed and I had ensured it was running when I executed the curl command.